# Weird background artifact

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How do I remove that artifact (marked with a blue circle)[image: enter image description here!!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem whas crated by the power node that crated a mirror. I removed the mirror by seting all valus below 0 to 0.[image]